# returning the first digit of an integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays, operators

I have a method and I am interested in knowing how it actually works. I have searched the internet, but to no avail. This method when used returns the first digit of an entered integer in to an array.

What puzzles me is the divide AND operator. I know that the operator divides an operand on the left with the operator on the right and applies the answer to the left side.

Here is the method:

```
public static int firstDigit(int index) 
{
    while (index > 9)
        index /= 10;
    return (index);

}
```

In my program when an integer is entered, say 100 it reads out the number 1, as its the first number of the entered integer.

shouldn't this answer be 10, because index =  100 /= 10 = 10?

Sorry if im doing it wrong, i'm new here and at programming, i did a considerable amount of research before i asked this question.

Comment: Do you know what loop is? Consider reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Comment: What you're missing is the while loop. You code keeps dividing index by 10 until the result is less than 10 then returns the result. So in this case 100 is divided by 10 twice to return 1.

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't this answer be 10, because index = 100 /= 10 = 10?

No.  10 is more than 9, so it divides it again.

The key part here is the `while` loop.  In the function above, it was written without brackets, but it could be rewritten as

```
public static int firstDigit(int index) 
{
    while (index > 9) 
    {
        index /= 10;
    }
    return (index);
}
```

I'm not going to explain what a while loop is in detail, but it basically repeats the process **while** the condition is true.

So in the case of 100, it does this:
"Is index more than 9?" Yes.  Set index to index/10.  (Index now equals 10).  "Is index more than 9?" Yes.  Set index to index/10.  (Index now equals 1).  "Is index more than 9?"  No.  Return index.  (1).

In the case of 99, it does this:
"Is index more than 9?" Yes.  Set index to index/10.  (Index now equals 9.9, round that to 9).  "Is index more than 9?"  No.  Return index.  (9).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I completely glanced over the while loop. I'll remember that in future.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the input is 100 :

You start with `index = 100`

then `index = index / 10 = 10`

since `10 > 9`, you divide by `10` again :

`index = index / 10 = 1`

Then you exit the loop and return `1`.

Basically, what this method does is compute `index / 10^(n-1)`, where n is the number of digits. This gives you the most significant digit.

Answer (score 0):

The line with `while` in it means that the following line (the one that does the division) happens repeatedly until the number that's left is less than ten. So 100 is divided by 10 to give 10, and then 10 is divided by 10 to give 1, which is returned.

Answer (score 0):

> *shouldn't this answer be 10, because index = 100 /= 10 = 10?*

No, it shouldn't. **Why?** Because of the *while loop*

```
while (index > 9)
```

in the first iteration, `index` enters in the loop as `100`, and it is modified to `100/10 = 10`.

Then, the condition `index > 9` is evaluated. Since it's `true` (`10 > 9`) the program continues with the next iteration. Therefore, `index` is modified to `10/10 = 1`.

The condition is evaluated again `index > 9`, but this time it's `false` (`1 > 9`), so the program exits the loop and *returns* the last value of `index`, 1.